# Display all mapfile layers with Openlayers

Tags: wms, mapserver, mapfile, openlayers

I'm using the following code to display my mapfile layers:

```
var wmsSource = new ol.source.ImageWMS({
            url: 'http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?MAP=/ms4w/apps/GEO/test.map',
            params: {'LAYERS': 'layer1,layer2...layerN'},
            serverType: 'mapserver',
            crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
});
```

Is there any simpler solution instead of typing all the layer names?

I mean something like this:
    `params: {'LAYERS': all}` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MapServer supports `LAYERS=all` as CGI parameter, but not in the WMS interface.

But you can use the name of the root layer, which is "MS" by default, and can be set with the `wms_rootlayer_name` metadata property.

Comment: you can also use group layers